# Jquery Validations not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am new to Jquery / Javascript

I am trying to validate a form to make sure that the fields have a value but i am getting the following Message in the console log

Error Message:

```
TypeError: "#post_origin".val is not a function
```

Script:

```
<script>

    $('#new_note_form').on('submit', function (event) {
        $(".errors").empty().remove();
        $.each($('#post_origin, #post_dest, #post_radius, #post_available, #post_equipment, #post_notes, #post_origin_states, #post_dest_states'), function(i, field) {
            $(field).css({ "border": '#FFFFFF 1px solid'});
        });


        if(('#post_origin').val() == '' && ('#post_origin_states').val() == '' ){
            ('#post_origin').css({ "border": '#FF0000 2px solid'});
            ('#post_origin_states').css({ "border": '#FF0000 2px solid'});
            (".errors").empty().append('Origin City/State & Origin States Can\'t Both Be Blank');
            return false
        }
        if(('#available').val() == ''){
            ('#available').css({ "border": '#FF0000 2px solid'});
            (".errors").empty().append('Available Date Can\'t Be Blank');
            return false
        }

    });



</script>
```

Comment: `('#post_origin').val()` (and other references to `(#post_origin)` and `('#available')`) are missing a leading `$`. Instead of jQuery objects, you're trying to call `val()` on parenthesized strings. See also `(".errors")` which should be `$(".errors")`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you mean to get a jQuery object using `$('#post_origin')`, as `('#post_origin')`is not valid. You do this a couple more times, make sure you get jQuery objects by doing: `$('selector')`.

Also, know that if you want to save a jQuery object to a variable, you can do that with `var variableName = $('selector')`.

Comment: Although I'm on Flynn's side in preferring semicolons, they *are* optional in Javascript. Those `return false` lines are perfectly valid.

Comment: You're right, I just overstepped my wanting to fix his styling. Editing to make my answer more on target with what was being asked.